# Are cookies kept in a Mechanize browser between opening URLs?

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I have code similar to this:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://mysite.com/")
br.select_form(nr=0)
#do stuff here
response = br.submit()
html = response.read()

#now that i have the login cookie i can do this...
br.open("https://mysite.com/")
html = response.read()
```

However, my script is responding like it's not logged in for the second request. I checked the first request and yes, it logs in successfully. My question is: do cookies in **Mechanize browsers** need to be managed or do I need to setup a CookieJar or something, or does it keep track of all of them for you?

The first example [here](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html) talks about cookies being carried between requests, but they don't talk about browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will have to store the `cookie` between `open` requests in `mechanize`. Something similar to the below should work as you can add the `cookiejar` to the `br` object and as long as that object exists it maintains that cookie.

```
import Cookie
import cookielib
cookiejar =cookielib.LWPCookieJar()

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)
br.open("https://mysite.com/")
br.select_form(nr=0)
#do stuff here
response = br.submit()
html = response.read()

#now that i have the login cookie i can do this...
br.open("https://mysite.com/")
html = response.read()
```

The [Docs](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html#supplying-a-cookiejar) cover it in more detail.

I use `perl` `mechanize` alot, but not `python` so I may have missed something `python` specific for this to work, so if I did I apologize, but I did not want to answer with a simple `yes`.

Comment: Thank-you, I will add a cookiejar. I assumed a *browser* would keep all this data. Bad name for that mechanize object! lol

Comment: macdonjo lemme know if it was simply adding the `cookiejar` or if you needed to do anything else. I am curious as to how it works in `python` and can't test it right now

Comment: Yup that worked. Just needed those 3 lines:
import cookiejar
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)