# Mechanize can't open URL

Tags: python, networking

So I try `r = br.open('https://beststresser.com')` but this is the output I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DDoS.py", line 15, in <module>
    r = br.open('https://beststresser.com')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 203, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 255, in _mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 503: Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

When I try another URL such as `r = br.open('https://google.com')` it works fine. But https://beststresser.com is a valid URL...

Comment: The site uses a DDoS attack protection mechanism. And it seems you are attacking the site (noting the filename in your post which is `DDoS.py`), If you have tried many times then this error should be normal.

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi No, I'm not trying to attack the website. I just want to access it and print its HTML source afterwards. But first I want to access the website. I've named it "DDoS.py" because the site itself is about DDoSing... (I am not trying to do anything illegal/harmful)

Comment: Have you tried `Selenium`?

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi I am sure that would work (I have much experience with this) but I don't want a window popping up and everything.. I want this to be Terminal-only interface.

Comment: That can be solved. There's a headless browser, named `PhantomJS`. You can use it with `Selenium`.

Comment: By the way, if you just want to get the HTML source, you can send a GET request using `requests` library or anything of that sort. The response will contain the HTML source of the page you requested.

Comment: If after all, you still insist to solve the `mechanize` issue, tell me so that I install the tool and test it. Currently I can't.

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi I looked it up and I realized that you need to import cookies to access Cloudflare websites. Cloudflare allows cookies (common visitors) to get into the site without waiting 5 seconds.

||| Theoretical solution: Go to the cloudflare protected website, get the cookies, use them in mechanize (import them). Then it won't be asking you to wait 5 seconds. Then you can work your way around normally. I am just unfamiliar how to import cookies with mechanize. If you do, let me know! :)

Comment: See if this helps [Are cookies kept in a Mechanize browser between opening URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840374/are-cookies-kept-in-a-mechanize-browser-between-opening-urls)

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi So I tried creating my Selenium code and adding/replacing these: `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()` and 
`driver.set_window_size(1280, 800)` But no luck. In Selenium/Firefox, it works fine. When I change webdriver.PhantomJS()  Nothing works unfortunately. My Code: http://pastebin.com/EYvL37k5

Comment: `PhantomJS` has no window; it is headless. By the way, have you installed `PhantomJS`? If you are in Linux, use apt-get or other package managers to install it; and if you are in Windows, download it and put `PhantomJS.exe` beside your `.py` file (or add it in $PATH).

Comment: @AhmadSiavashi Looks like I've installed it;

`root@kali:~/Desktop# phantomjs --version
1.9.8
root@kali:~/Desktop# `